# Backbone: TypeError: Unedfined is not a function

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am VERY new to both Javascript and Backbone in particular. Based on a couple tutorials, I wrote the following code:

```
var app = app || {};

app.City = Backbone.Model.extend();

app.CityCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: app.City,
    url: "http:127.0.0.1:8000/api/listing/city"
});

app.District = Backbone.Model.extend();

app.DistrictCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: app.District,
    url: "http:127.0.0.1:8000/api/listing/district"
});

app.Advert = Backbone.Model.extend();

app.AdvertCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: app.Advert,
    url: "http:127.0.0.1:8000/api/listing/advert"
});

app.AdvertListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagname:'table',

    intialize: function () {
        this.model.bind("reset", this.render, this);
    },

    render:function (eventName) {
        _.each(this.model.models, function (advert) {
            $(this.el).append(new AdvertListItemView({model:advert}).render().el);
        }, this);
        return this;
    }
});

app.AdvertListItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagname:'td',
    template: _.template($('#advert-list-item').html()),

    render:function (eventName) {
        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});

var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes:{
        "":"list",
        "advert/:id":"advertDetails"
    },

    list:function() {
        this.app.AdvertList = new app.AdvertCollection();
        this.app.advertListView = new app.AdvertListView({model:this.advertList});
        this.app.AdvertList.fetch();
        $('#advert-list-item').html(this.advertListView.render().el);
    }
});

var app = new AppRouter();
Backbone.history.start();
```

I get the following error message when I try to load the page in a browser:

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function in line 61. Line 61 is the following:

```
this.app.AdvertList = new app.AdvertCollection();
```

I'd appreciate any ideas where my mistake is.

Answer (score 1):

the problem you have here is with scope. You are referencing `this.app.AdvertList` but  `this.app` is undefined. Remove `this` from your list function.

The `this` on line 61 refers to the object that is running the code. In this case that object is `AppRouter`. Since `Approuter.app.AdvertList` is undefined, you get that error.